# Handling DOM elements in PHP JSON API

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, google-maps

The scenario is something like this,

1. Our mobile app hits our JSON API on server.
2. JSON API, which is actually a PHP script, processes the data and returns results to the app in JSON format.

Now the API has two main elements,
1. It makes use of Google maps to perform certain actions. So it has all its Javascript in the code of API that plots the map, makers, take decisions etc.
2. It also has PHP code that saves the data in database and return the result set.
3. Result set is formatted returned using json_encode.

When we pass the parameters to this API using web or browser, it works perfectly. Does everything as desired.
But when the same API is called by the mobile app, it raises error. Because it sees Javascript int. App is only expecting the JSON in it. To confirm this, we called API from browser, view source code,and it has all the Javascript there. Because JS is technically client side code, so its returned. Even though its only used for processing via Google maps.

Any ideas or workarounds for this? How can we do calculations using Google maps, yet the app doesn't see Javascript?

As a workaround, I used ob_start and ob_end_clear. But what it does was, it was clearing the JS before execution. So error was gone but JS wasn't working at all.

Second solution we tried was to strip down JS code at the Application end. But than we found that API was doing all the PHP part, but not the JS part. Javascript was all there but it wasn't simply working. So we realized that, JS probably needs a medium/a browser to work. Specially when its a DOM element like Google maps.

Any ideas how to do Google maps related processing on server-end when mobile hits our web service? We also used Curl, include file, Ajax. None worked. I am just missing the logic.

We have to play with user's location using Google maps.

Thanks!